# Dynamically size the header section based on the content size with a min and max Height

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to achieve the below screen

[Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pygXW.png)

Screen is divided into 2 parts :

1. The header part (min height 30%, max 50% of the screen height)
2. The content part

The content decides the height of the header. If the content is  minimal and can be displayed fully, then header height = 50% (2nd screen in Image)
If content is more than what can be displayed, shrink the header height to 30% and let the content fill up the space (1st screen in Image)

I have tried barrier and guidelines, I can make something where the bottom view size is limited but unable to create something where the top part height is varying.

Appreciate any help on this, TIA!